# How Can I have a Flash AS3 Projector load protected content?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, passwords, protected

How Can I have a Flash AS3 Projector load protected images/mp3s/videos from a password protected server?  I have a bunch of content in a password protected directory that I do not want people to access unless it is in my flash Projector.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

1.-Put the images in a non-protected folder with any name except images or img 
2.-Set "Options -indexes" in your apache server configuration file or in a .htaccess file in your root directory
3.-Then link your Projector normally to the images.

Hope this helps